# Proof verification: Deciding if 3 rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I am trying to figure out if any of the following rings are isomorphic
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]}{(2)},\;\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]}{(2)},\;
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]}{(1+\sqrt{-3})}
$$
I believe two of them are and I think I can write each down in a simpler way but am hoping to confirm.

I think 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]}{(2)}\cong \{ a+bx:\;a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
since we may equivalently first quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by $2$ and then by $x^2-1$, killing all quadratic terms and above.

Similarly, I think 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]}{(2)}=\{ a+bx:\;a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]}{(1+\sqrt{-3})}\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}
$$
since this is equivalent to first mapping $x$ to $1$ and then $4$ to $0$.

Comment: How does modding out $x^2-1$ kill the linear terms?

Comment: $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]}{(2)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2-5,2)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2-1,2)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{5}]/(2) \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x+1)^2 \cong \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$$

This is the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) over $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$. The first isomorphism is because $$x^2 - 5 \equiv x^2 - 1 \equiv (x - 1)(x + 1) \equiv (x+1)^2 \pmod 2. $$ The second is the substitution $\varepsilon = x + 1$.

The ring $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(2)$ is isomorphic to the same ring. It is not isomorphic (as a ring) to $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ since, for example, $\sqrt{-2}$ is a non-zero element whose square is $0$; no element of  $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ has this property.

The last ring is indeed isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ and not isomorphic to the first two because every element of $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$ has order 2.

Comment: Thank you for your help and introducing me to the dual numbers! I realized multiplication didn't carry over to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^2$ after posting. This clarifies everything